# Trying to set up codepipeline in Bahrain(me-south-1) region in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline, aws-code-deploy, aws-codebuild

I am trying to set up a code pipeline in the Bahrain region in aws console.

But the code pipeline is not available in that region.
So I tried to follow [this](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/using-aws-codepipeline-to-perform-multi-region-deployments/) doc which briefly states that we can have a pipeline in other region and have only the cod deploy part in the region where my EC2 machines are present.

So I tried and created a code deploy application in Bahrain region and have my code pipeline in us-east-1.

My code pipeline has 2 stages :

```
1. repo(github)
2. Code build.
```

When I try to add the 3rd step of code deploy, I am not able to find the region in the drop-down.

[image]

As you can see the drop-down doesn't have the Bahrain region(i checked all the options in the drop-down).

could you please help in finding a way to set up CodePipeline to have my deployment on Bahrain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this could be because the specific AWS provider or CodePipline (CP) are not available for your region. From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/actions-create-cross-region.html):

> Certain action types in CodePipeline may only be available in certain AWS Regions. Also note that there may be AWS Regions where an action type is available, but a **specific AWS provider** for that action type is **not available**.

In this case, you would have to "manually" trigger your CodeDeploy deployment in Bahrain region. This would require **modification of your CP**.

For instance, you could add CodeBuild (CB) or lambda action to your CP to copy the artifact from the CP's bucket to a bucket in the Bahrain region. Then, the same lambda function or CB would trigger the CodeDeploy (CD) in the Bahrain region using AWS SDK.

Comment: could you help me out with this.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63933864/buildspec-yaml-for-serverless-framework-in-aws-code-pipleline