# Buildspec.yaml for serverless framework in aws code pipleline

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless-framework, aws-codepipeline, aws-code-deploy, aws-codebuild

I  am trying my hands on CI/CD pipeline for serverless framework.

I had done a similar thing for SAM framework and had got it working.
SAM framework has two steps of package and deploy (deploy is handled by cloudformation actions)

```
version: 0.2
phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
        nodejs: 10
        #trying after adding the art effect in code deploy  
  build:
    commands:
      - npm install time
      - export BUCKET=lambda-loadeo-git
      - aws cloudformation package --template-file template.yml --s3-bucket $BUCKET --output-template-file outputtemplate.yml
artifacts:
  type: zip
  files:
    - template.yml
    - outputtemplate.yml
```

But I am not so sure how serverless should work.
I know serverless had only 'deploy' stage and no package and all.

I don't know how deployment is handled here in CI/CD for serverless. which is giving error at serverless deploy command.

Here is my buildspec.yaml file

```
version: 0.1
phases:
  install:
    commands:
      - npm install
      - npm install -g mocha
      - npm install -g serverless
  build:
    commands:
      - serverless deploy 
  post_build:
    commands:

      - echo build complete
```

which is trying to deploy this template:

```
service: serverless
frameworkVersion: '2'

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python2.7
  profile: default 


functions:
  getInfo:
    handler: handler.getInfo
    events:
     - http:
        path: users/info
        method: get

  createInfo:
    handler: handlerpost.createInfo
    events:
     - http:
        path: users/create
        method: post

  patchInfo:
    handler: handlerpatch.patchInfo
    events:
     - http:
        path: users/update
        method: patch
```

Could anyone help me out with the build and deploy part of this?

Comment: Could you clarify which error exactly you are getting when you write "which is giving error at serverless deploy command." and which line produces it?

Comment: @Marcin.
Phase context status code: COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR Message: Error while executing command: serverless deploy. Reason: exit status 1

Comment: found this in the log "This command can only be run in a Serverless service directory. Make sure to reference a valid config file in the current working directory if you're using a custom config file"

Comment: Can you add `- ls -la` before line with `- serverless deploy` to list all the files present when you run deploy?

Comment: @Marcin have edited the question with the output

Comment: I think its looking for `serverless.yml`. In the printout there is no such file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221617/discussion-between-sumanth-shetty-and-marcin).

Comment: How did it go with permissions?

Comment: @Marcin had to add api gateway and lambda permissions as well. 
Got it working. But how  would I be handling the deployment stage if I don't want to deploy in Buildspec itself ? might be elementary but had to ask

Comment: Hi. From what I remember, you can't use CodePipline provider for CodeDeploy in your region. I think, if not CB, then lambda could be possible used. You can make new question with any code you have for that or errors. This way others on SO can also view it and try to help.

Comment: @Marcin could you help me out on this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63985825/restricting-users-of-the-cognito-user-group-to-accessing-api-gateway-end-point

Comment: Sadly, I don't use much Cognito, thus can't help much with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments and chat discussion.

There were a **few issues** causing problems:

1. Missing `serverless.yml`. It was solved by renaming `template.yml` into `serverless.yml`.
2. Wrong profile in serverless provider. It was addressed by removing it.
3. Missing permission in CodeBuild role. This was rectified by adding codeformation, s3 and cloudwatch logs permissions to the role.