# Restricting users of the cognito user group to accessing API gateway end point

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, authorization, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I am trying my hands on Cognito and trying to restrict the authorization to a few API endpoints through the console.

1. Have different groups in the Cognito user pool (broker, carrier).
2. Have different API in API gateway for both(broker, carrier).
3. Restrict the access in such a way that the broker group can only access the API of the broker and the carrier access the API of the carrier.

Things I have done:

1. I have created a user pool and have added a group (broker and carrier)
2. I have designed a few demo API to Check if I can restrict access.
3. I have checked that we can restrict access to API through the user pool by configuring API authorization to Cognito and Cognito generates a JWT token for the user pool. (But I am looking at group level).

Could anyone suggest how can I restrict access such that the broker group can access APIs designed for broker and carrier group access APIs designed for the carrier?

Comment: So to confirm, you have multiple APIs but a single Cognito group?

Comment: @ChrisWilliams, I have one user pool within that I have 2 user groups (broker and carrier).
Have two sets of APIs(which perform CRUD operation for groups) one for the broker and another for the carrier. What I am trying to achieve is broker should have access to only broker API

Comment: Have you looked at custom authorizers?

Comment: @RodrigoM, I have gone through some costume authorization Which is present in this link.
https://medium.com/@awskarthik82/part-1-securing-aws-api-gateway-using-aws-cognito-oauth2-scopes-410e7fb4a4c0

Here they are using Hosted UI in cognito to generate the JWT token which. But when I try it with a Web app the joken generated doesn't have the proper scope. 

Is there some other way to achieve it

Comment: Did you find any solution?